# Bootstrap 3 Table inside a panel overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
         <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">Recently Filtered</div>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr><td>Sensor ID</td><td>Temperature</td><td>Voltage</td><td>Date</td>
            <tr><td>Sensor ID</td><td>Temperature</td><td>Voltage</td><td>Date</td>
            <tr><td>Sensor ID</td><td>Temperature</td><td>Voltage</td><td>Date</td>
            <tr><td>Sensor ID</td><td>Temperature</td><td>Voltage</td><td>Date</td>
          </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

The table inside a panel is overflowing when I zoom in, here's a picture example[image]

What's the proper mark up accommodating this problem? I know that it can scale properly for sure.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could always add `.table-responsive` class to the table to get it scroll horizontally. Example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

If that isn't what you're wanting, you'll need to lower the font size to make it fit better.

Comment: Looks like you are right, according to bootstrap itself: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: Technically, you nest the table *within* a `div.table-responsive` rather than putting the class on the table itself.

Answer (score 7):

it appears to only happen when the viewport has responded down to mobile sizes. The easiest fix is to add `overflow` rule.

```
.panel {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

you could also change font sizes or remove unneeded table cells. You could also abbreviate

- ID
- Temp
- V
- Date

Comment: This will just make a scrollable content, I've seen it done without it which scales properly. Example: http://themeforest.net/item/madmin-responsive-multistyle-admin-template/full_screen_preview/7996710?ref=designrazzi Under tables

Comment: @Aaron did you ever figure out how to scale the table properly? I also am looking for the behavior shown in the basic responsive table at the link you shared
EDIT: nevermind, that basic responsive table also fails w/ long content

Comment: @sabliao Adjust the font-size or wrap around `div-responsive`

Comment: Line chart in the theme actually pushes out of the panel in the mobile demo on chrome...

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, you tryed to add a div with class panel-body around the table?

Comment: Your answer is a solution, but if you read the bootstrap docs on panels, [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) tables are intended to be siblings with the .panel-body class.