# asp.net with bootstrap. table-responsive scrolling is broken in panel-body

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage with the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:auto;height:auto;">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="ContentHeader" runat="server" style="width:auto;height:auto;">Table</div>
    <div class="panel-body" runat="server" style="width:auto;height:auto;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <asp:GridView ID="ExcelContentView" runat="server" class="table table-bordered" >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="info" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i reference [this pages answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071030/bootstrap-3-table-inside-a-panel-overflowing)

it works fine **only** with overflow-x.

[image]

however, scroll bar is broken when overflow-x with overflow-y case.

About 53 rows and 15 columns:

[image]

vertical scrollbar is not working. 
but Left Or Right Key is move scrollbar.
clicking scrollbar is broken i think.

how do i fix scroll bar in overflow x and y case?

here is additional c# code behind

on page load :

```
    {
        ExcelContentView.DataSource = ExcelViewManager.Instance.GetExcelViewTable(fileName, historyNum);
            ExcelContentView.DataBind();

    } // method
```

and GetExcelViewTable Method

```
    {
        DataTable stringTable = new DataTable();

        var currType = GameDataFileManager.Instance.GetTypeFromFileName(fileName);

        string historyPath = GameDataFileManager.Instance.GetHistoryPathByType(currType);

        string fullPath = historyPath + fileName + revNum + ".xlsx";

        FileInfo excelFileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);

        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(excelFileInfo);

        var workSheet1 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

        int colCount = 0;

        //  
        for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= workSheet1.Dimension.End.Column; ++iCol )
        {
            stringTable.Columns.Add( workSheet1.Cells[1, iCol].Text, typeof(string) );
            ++colCount;
        } // for 


        for (int iRow = 3; iRow <= workSheet1.Dimension.End.Row; ++iRow )
        {
            List<object> objList = new List<object>();

            for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= workSheet1.Dimension.End.Column; ++iCol )
            {

                objList.Add( workSheet1.Cells[iRow, iCol].Text );
            } // for 

            int objCount = objList.Count;

            if (colCount != objCount)
            {
                DotNetMsgBox.Show("Debug");
            }

            stringTable.Rows.Add(objList.ToArray());

        } // for 

        return stringTable;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:auto;height:auto;"> try <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-12 col-lg-12" >

Comment: <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-12 col-lg-12" > is didnt works. it has same problem with <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:auto;height:auto;"> . only scrolling in less row table.

Comment: Give your full code please.

Comment: We are not getting the table data

Comment: im not using static table data. it is dynamically making data.

Comment: this problem is from "many row table" data. i mean, row data size is larger than panel height, scroll bar is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

table-responsive is broken scrollbar when using with [simple sidebar](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

responsive broken when this code.

```
<li class="sidebar-footer">Made by Me</li>
```

so, this sidebar-footer code makes problem.

i dont know why this code broken table-responisve sidebar.

i open simple-sidbar.css, and see this codes

```
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-footer {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

and i delete code in { }, but still has problem.

so, i delete sidebar-footer in my Master Page. and yes. i solved problem.

anyone tell me why this sidebar-footer broken scrollbar.